# Calculate duration between two rows T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good afternoon! Could anyone help me to solve the task? I have a table:

| Id | Date | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 10:00 | Departure |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 12:20 | Arrival |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 14:30 | Departure |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 19:20 | Arrival |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 15:40 | Departure |
| 1 | 2020-01-04 19:20 | Arrival |
| 2 | 2020-02-03 15:40 | Departure |
| 2 | 2020-02-04 19:20 | Arrival |
| 3 | 2020-03-05 15:40 | Departure |
| 3 | 2020-03-05 19:20 | Arrival |
| 3 | 2020-03-06 16:28 | Departure |
| 3 | 2020-03-06 21:00 | Arrival |

I need to estimate average duration of each ID. At first step I want to get table, for example for id = 1,  as

| Id | Duraton (minutes) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 140 |
| 1 | 290 |
| 1 | 1660 |

How can I achive that by T-Sql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rows are perfectly interleaved, you can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(minute, date, next_date) as diff_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where reason = 'Departure';
```

If you want the results for only one `id`, you can filter in either the subquery or the outer query.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought about lead() over(), but some how I didn't think about using it in subquery